# Disable logging from ActiveMQ Java client

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I set up ActiveMQ, and I'm sending a message to it with Java. This is a simple tryout, nothing fancy (BTW I might be doing it wrong, explaining all the sysout, never used ActiveMQ before). I loop and send like 10k messages to the queue, but it is logging every single send in the console like this:

```
DEBUG 12 Mar 2021 11:28:45 main - [org.apache.activemq.thread.TaskRunnerFactory]:98 - Initialized TaskRunnerFactory[ActiveMQ Session Task] using ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@5622fdf[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
DEBUG 12 Mar 2021 11:28:45 main - [org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator]:82 - Sending: WireFormatInfo { version=12, properties={StackTraceEnabled=true, PlatformDetails=Java, CacheEnabled=true, Host=XXXXXXXXXXX, TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, CacheSize=1024, ProviderName=ActiveMQ, TightEncodingEnabled=true, MaxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, ProviderVersion=5.16.1}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]}
DEBUG 12 Mar 2021 11:28:45 ActiveMQ Transport: XXXXXXXXXXXXX - [org.apache.activemq.transport.InactivityMonitor]:103 - Using min of local: WireFormatInfo { version=12, properties={StackTraceEnabled=true, PlatformDetails=Java, CacheEnabled=true, Host=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, CacheSize=1024, ProviderName=ActiveMQ, TightEncodingEnabled=true, MaxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, ProviderVersion=5.16.1}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]} and remote: WireFormatInfo { version=12, properties={TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, CacheSize=1024, ProviderName=ActiveMQ, StackTraceEnabled=true, PlatformDetails=Java, CacheEnabled=true, TightEncodingEnabled=true, MaxFrameSize=104857600, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, ProviderVersion=5.16.1}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]}
DEBUG 12 Mar 2021 11:28:45 ActiveMQ Transport: XXXXXXXXXXXXX - [org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator]:130 - Received WireFormat: WireFormatInfo { version=12, properties={TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, CacheSize=1024, ProviderName=ActiveMQ, StackTraceEnabled=true, PlatformDetails=Java, CacheEnabled=true, TightEncodingEnabled=true, MaxFrameSize=104857600, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, ProviderVersion=5.16.1}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]}
DEBUG 12 Mar 2021 11:28:45 ActiveMQ Transport: XXXXXXXXXXXXX - [org.apache.activemq.transport.WireFormatNegotiator]:137 - XXXXXXXXXXXXX before negotiation: OpenWireFormat{version=12, cacheEnabled=false, stackTraceEnabled=false, tightEncodingEnabled=false, sizePrefixDisabled=false, maxFrameSize=9223372036854775807}
```

How can I disable this as this is resulting in a very slow sending due to the fact that it is logging so much?

I think i should be able to change the level of logging to something higher than `DEBUG` like `WARN`? Is it server side or client side & where are the files located if I'm right?

Comment: Share your logging configuration file for specifics

Comment: I dont know where is the configuration for the logger file, is it on client side or server side ?

Comment: How are you running your test code? Command line or in a IDE project, such as Eclipse? There is probably a log4j.properties (or similar) file.

Comment: I'm starting it from Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had no file for the log4j configuration so i did create one under `/src/main/resources` and used this configuration :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="false"
    xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%5p %d{yyyy.MM.dd_HH:mm:ss} - vdf-loader - (%t) [%c]:%L - %m\n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="D:\\PATH\\TO\\YOUR\\LOGS\\vdf-loader.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="false" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%5p %d{yyyy.MM.dd_HH:mm:ss} - vdf-loader - (%t) [%c]:%L - %m\n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<--! configuration of ActiveMQ here -->
<category name="org.apache.activemq">
    <priority value="INFO" />
</category>

// more categories...

<root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
</root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

These messages are being logged due to your logger configuration. Confirm you do not have a global DEBUG level set.